# Django: update view based on the data from the form

Tags: python, html, django

I'm a django newbie.

I use the DetailView to view a list of graphs on the page:

```
class WidgetDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):                                                   

    model         = Widget
    template_name = 'board/detail.html'
    form_class    = SelectForm
    period        = 86400

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('board:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WidgetDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        context['form'] = self.get_form(form_class)
        context['period'] = self.period
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

I have a simple form with simple select:

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):                     
    CHOICES = (                                   
        ('3600',     u'1 h'),                   
        ('7200',     u'2 h'),                  
        ('10800',    u'3 h'),                  
        ('21600',    u'6 h'),                 
        ('43200',    u'12 h'),                
        ('86400',    u'1 d'),                  
        ('604800',   u'1 w'),                
        ('1209600',  u'2 w'),                
        ('2592000',  u'1 m'),                 
        ('7776000',  u'3 m'),                
        ('15552000', u'6 m'),               
        ('31536000', u'1 y'),                     
    )                                             

    select = forms.ChoiceField(                   
        widget = forms.Select(                    
            attrs = {                             
                'class': 'form-control  input-sm',
                'onchange': 'this.form.submit();',
            }                                     
        ),                                        
        choices = CHOICES,                        
        label = u'Period'                        
    )
```

HTML code:

```
{% extends 'board/base.html' %}                                                                                     
{% block content %}                                                                                                 
<div class="page-header">                                                                                       
    <h2>{{ widget.title }}</h2>                                                                                 
    <p>{{ widget.description }}</p>                                                                             
</div>
{% if widget.graph_set.all %}                                                                                   
<form method="post" action="." role="form" class="form-inline">                                                 
    {% csrf_token %}                                                                                            
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Period</label>                                                       
    <div class="form-group">                                                                                    
    {{ form.select }}                                                                                           
    </div>                                                                                                      
</form>                                                                                                         
{% endif %}                                                                                                     

<div class="row">                                                                                               
{% for graph in widget.graph_set.all %}                                                                         
<div class="col-md-6">                                                                                          
    <h3>{{ graph.title }}</h3>                                                                                  
    <img src="https://zabbix.net.eximb.com/zabbix/chart2.php?graphid={{ graph.graph_id }}&width=400&height=200&period={{ period }}" alt="{{ graph.title }}">
    <p>{{ graph.description }}</p>
</div>
{% empty %}
<p>No graphs</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

So I want to reload page after selecting period from the dropdown. How can I update the form (it is always set to default after submitting) and pass the `{{ period }}` to the template?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my form method from POST to GET. Now if you select option from the list the form gets the initial data from GET request.

Also, the code became much simplier:

**views.py**:

```
class WidgetDetailView(DetailView):
    model         = Widget
    template_name = 'board/detail.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)                   
        return super(WidgetDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WidgetDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = SelectForm(initial=self.request.GET)
        context['period'] = self.request.GET.get('select', 86400)
        return context
```

**detail.html**:

```
...
<form method="get" action="." role="form" class="form-inline">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Масштаб</label>     
    <div class="form-group">                                  
    {{ form.select }}                                         
    </div>                                                    
 </form>
...
```